# How to pass javascript class variables between files

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have the following code in a typescript file:

**attributes.ts**

```
export class AttributesPage {
    chart: any[];

    constructor(
    //Assigning values to chartArray
    var chartArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    //Should define the chart variable
    this.chart = chartArray

        })
    }
}
```

I want to assign the `chart` variable to a parameter in my .html file but am not able to pass it through and use it in the `chart-here` tag.

**attributes.html**

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-card-header>

            //Displays 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 
            {{this.chartArray}}

            //Displays 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
            {{this.chart}}

            //Undefined
            {{chart}}

        <ion-card-content>

                //When I try to assign the values of the variables to the [readings] parameter in <chart-here>
                     //"this.chartArray": undefined
                     //"this.chart": undefined
                     //"chart": undefined
                <chart-here [readings]= "chart"></chart-here>               

              </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card-header>
```

Alternatively, this works:

**attributes.html**

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>

                <chart-here [readings]= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]></chart-here>               

              </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card-header>
```

As well as when I define the chart variable in my .ts page:

**attributes.ts**

```
export class AttributesPage {
    chart: any[] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

    constructor()
}
```

How can I define my **chart variable** or **pass through this.chartArray/this.chart as variable** to the `chart-here` tag?

Any input or help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is `chart-here`? is it a component can you post the code for that? `readings` should have a @input decorator to accept the value as array.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your code from the constructor to the ngOnInit method like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.chart = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
}
```